# Absolute div with 100% height doesn't cover entire body of modal scrollable

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap modal scrollable and I want to cover it with a white-transparent absolute div, I set the modal body in relative position and the absolute div is 100% height and the top/bottom is set in 0, but when I scroll, the absolute div stays in the same place and it doesn't cover the entire body

```css
.modal-body {
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
}

#loading {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

    <title>Bootstrap Modal</title>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#staticBackdrop">
        Launch static backdrop modal
    </button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="staticBackdrop" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1"
        aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Modal title</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply a dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been
                        the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s when an unknown printer took a galley
                        of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries,
                        but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was
                        popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
                        and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of
                        Lorem Ipsum.
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply a dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been
                        the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s when an unknown printer took a galley
                        of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries,
                        but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was
                        popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
                        and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of
                        Lorem Ipsum.
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply a dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been
                        the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s when an unknown printer took a galley
                        of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries,
                        but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was
                        popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
                        and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of
                        Lorem Ipsum.
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply a dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been
                        the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s when an unknown printer took a galley
                        of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries,
                        but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was
                        popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
                        and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of
                        Lorem Ipsum.
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply a dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been
                        the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s when an unknown printer took a galley
                        of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries,
                        but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was
                        popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
                        and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of
                        Lorem Ipsum.
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply a dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been
                        the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s when an unknown printer took a galley
                        of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries,
                        but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was
                        popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
                        and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of
                        Lorem Ipsum.
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply a dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been
                        the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s when an unknown printer took a galley
                        of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries,
                        but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was
                        popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
                        and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of
                        Lorem Ipsum.
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply a dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been
                        the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s when an unknown printer took a galley
                        of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries,
                        but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was
                        popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
                        and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of
                        Lorem Ipsum.
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply a dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been
                        the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley
                        of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries,
                        but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was
                        popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
                        and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of
                        Lorem Ipsum.
                    </p>
                    <div id="loading"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Understood</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Fy6S3B9q64WdZWQUiU+q4/2Lc9npb8tCaSX9FK7E8HnRr0Jz8D6OP9dO5Vg3Q9ct"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're okay with changing the markup a bit you can maybe solve this by:

1. adding a parent div (.modal-body-wrap)
2. moving the #loader div outside of the .modal-body (scrolling) div
3. adjusting the styles a little bit (see below)

New markup:

```
<div class="modal-header">
  ...
</div>
<div class="modal-body-wrap">
    <div id="loading"></div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>
           Lorem ips...
```

Then change styles to:

```
.modal-body {
    height: 100%;
}

.modal-body-wrap {
    position: relative;
    max-height:75vh;
}

#loading {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index:1;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

This solution only works with support for pointer-events, though this has fairly wide adoption at this point: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Comment: Hello, i use the modal wrapper and it works, i can achieve my objective without pointer-events property. thank you!